# C# Interop Excel Macro With Password - Is It Possible?

Tags: c#, vba

Does anyone know if it is possible to run a macro embedded inside a workbook which has a password enabled?

Basically I am able to run a macro in a workbook already - However in my manager wants a freaking password added and I don't think thats possible

Has anyone managed to get this in place?

Comment: Where do you want the password added? Upon running of the macro? Or does the workbook have a password?

Comment: The workbook has a macro

Comment: Yes, I realize the workbook has a macro, but where should/does the password live?

Comment: Sorry the workbook has a password - Thats what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the Open method can be passed a password. However it's worth noting that hard-coded passwords are pretty trivial to extract from an exe. IMHO it's better to just catch the exception to the open method, prompt the user for the password, and then retry the open method with the provided password.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to open the workbook in code and then run the macro?

The open method on the workbook object accepts a password as a parameter.